# Using char*array to store a bar for a bar graph so I can dynamically make it and return as a string

Tags: c++

What my program does is it reads in a file char by char counting digits and letters only it then prints the data to the screen, with it labeled what particular digit or letter, that particular letters count, and then a bar representation of it.
I have already made an implementation of this that works with an empty string, using a for loop to append "=" on the string to form a bar. What I want to do with it instead is use a char* to dynamically create an char[] of x size. I use the following method to do so

```
//typedef casting
 typedef int index;
 typedef int char_count;
 typedef int index_constant;
 typedef int number_of_chars;
 typedef char next_char;
 typedef string bar;
 typedef string label;
 typedef string file;
 typedef string message;

     const bar build_bar(char_count x)
     {
           bar bar ="";
           char *bar_Holder = new char[x];
           for (size_t i = 0; i < x; i++)
           {
                bar_Holder[i] = '=';
           }
           bar = bar_Holder;
           delete[] bar_Holder;
           return bar;
     }
```

Then I print the graph to the screen using this method:

```
void print(digits_letters_counter x, int spacing)
{
    index j = 0;
    for (index i = 0; i < number_of_chars_counted; i++, j++)
    {
        if (i < 10) 
        {
            i = i + digit_index_range;
            cout << (char)i << ":" << setw(spacing) <<setfill(' ')<< build_label(x.digit_letter_counter[j])<< build_bar(x.digit_letter_counter[j]) << endl;
            i = i - digit_index_range;
        }
        else if (i >= 10) 
        {
            i = i + alpha_index_range;
            cout << (char)i << ":" << setw(spacing) << setfill(' ') << build_label(x.digit_letter_counter[j]) << build_bar(x.digit_letter_counter[j]) << endl;
            i = i - alpha_index_range;
        }
    }
}
```

When i run this code I will get an out put like this which will have the appropriate number of bars but will have junk data tagged onto the end of it.

> Enter the file name to be counted: sample.txt 0:3===²²²² 1:1=²²²²▌▌
>   2:4====²²²²Q 3:4====²²²²Q 4:2==²²²²▌▌Q 5:2==²²²²▌▌Q 6:4====²²²²Q
>   7:0²²²²▌▌▌▌Q 8:0²²²²▌▌▌▌Q 9:2==²²²²▌▌Q A:5=====²²²²▌▌▌▌▌▌▌v▌
>   B:1=²²²²▌▌▌Q C:0²²²²▌▌▌▌Q D:3===²²²²▌Q E:5=====²²²²▌▌▌▌▌▌▌RÇ▌
>   F:4====²²²²Q G:0²²²²▌▌▌▌Q
>   H:41=========================================²²²²y
>   I:5=====²²²²▌▌▌▌▌▌▌v▌ J:0²²²²▌▌▌▌Q K:1=²²²²▌▌▌Q L:4====²²²²Q
>   M:2==²²²²▌▌Q N:5=====²²²²▌▌▌▌▌▌▌┬0▌ O:4====²²²²Q P:1=²²²²▌▌▌Q
>   Q:0²²²²▌▌▌▌Q R:0²²²²▌▌▌▌Q S:9=========²²²²▌▌▌.▌ T:4====²²²²Q
>   U:0²²²²▌▌▌▌Q V:2==²²²²▌▌Q W:0²²²²▌▌▌▌Q X:1=²²²²▌▌▌Q Y:0²²²²▌▌▌▌Q
>   Z:0²²²²▌▌▌▌Q Press any key to continue . . .
>   My question is how do I get rid of the junk data or even prevent it from be allocated and stored like this?

Comment: Why don't you use an `std::string` or `std::vector<char>`?

Comment: in my solution I turned in i did just use a std::string and append "=" to the end of it, but I want to get better practice with pointer manipulation so I tried doing this with pointers and wanted to see if its doable or how I can prevent the junk data from forming.

Comment: Sorry for possible confusion I left off my typedefs!

Comment: A minimal verifiable source code needs to be shown here. You showed 1 function definition `build_bar` but you never showed `build_label` nor your main in how you are calling your `print` function and what is being passed to it as well as how you are reading in data from your file and how your file is formatted.

Comment: in the `print` function are a lot of types and variables you not defined. Please build a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Why do you use typedef as if you are defining variables? Whats the point of properly naming a variable then?

Comment: So its easier to go back and change types, its just a habit I try to keep no matter how small and simple the program is.

Comment: And for the people asking for a complete code its not necessary the alogrithm works all I was curious was why it had junk value tagged onto the end of the real values which Mr. Bo Persson answered beautifully

Comment: Soren and Francis please read entire question next time thoroughly

Comment: When you do `bar = bar_Holder`, bar_Holder has to be a valid null terminated string.

Comment: Again about typedef, I don't see how you can simply change the type without expecting to change any other code. Even for simple types like int and char, you might still need to carefully reexamine your code and make changes accordingly. For other types, you should probably make use of concepts like inheritance and interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get extra stuff at the end, because `cout` expects the string to be zero terminated. And you don't add a terminator.

You also cannot `delete[]` the string and return a pointer to it. This creates a dangling pointer, which causes undefined behavior when you use it.

Using a `std::string` would make the program a lot simpler and take care of these details automatically.

Comment: The pointer is stored in a string before I delete it so there should be no dangling pointer error, but I will make sure to zero terminate it, and as I said in my question I did use string to make it I just wanted more practice with char*

Comment: @Sean - Oh, so `bar` is a string. The you could just do `std::string bar(x, '=');` and be done.